# VB.NET: Inserting text right after the end of the paragraph

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

My goal is to create a word doc where in each letter has different fonts. Fonts will be randomly selected. Code seems working but the only problem is that I can't get the letters append right after the previous string. It keeps making new paragraph for each letter.

```vb
wp = wd.Content.Paragraphs.Add
wp.selection.Font.Name = font
wp.selection.TypeText = letter
```

Here's the result

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the `selection` property over `Range`.

Try replacing

```
wp.Range.Font.Name = font
wp.Range.Text = letter
```

with

```
wp.Selection.font.Name = font
wp.Selection.TypeText letter
```

`Selection` will be the current location of the cursor.

I'm not exactly sure of your intent with `wp.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()`, but I don't believe it's necessary to be in the `For Each . . . Next` loop.

Comment: It looks like Selection is not a member of a Paragraph. I might be missing something

Comment: Ah yes, your `wp` object declaration was not clear. Replace `wp` with the application obj. Although it makes more sense now since `Range()` is not a member of the application either.

Comment: Im sorry.I actually dont get it. I have edited the script from the main question. That might help me understand more

Comment: Okay thanks. So change `wp.` to `wa.` And were did the `paragraph.add` come from? Remove that line as well. At least put it before your loop.